# Can't read the numbers and values inside of a file in Java?

Tags: java, file-io

First of all excuse my bad typing errors and posting mistakes because I'm new to the site and still learning how use it.

I'm supposed to create a code that asks the user if he wants to deposit or withdraw and then asks him to enter the file name and then uses the info inside to add to the account; anyway this code is about 25% finished and I'm having trouble while testing the code so far, because it doesn't seem to read the file's name after I enter it when it asks me, Do you know what may cause this problem? any suggestions or a feedback?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class read {

    public static void main(String [] args)  throws FileNotFoundException {
        Double currentbalance = 500.00;
        System.out.println("To deposit enter 1");
        System.out.println("To Withdrwawl enter 2");
        Scanner depositOrWithdrawl = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choose = depositOrWithdrawl.nextInt();
        if(choose == 1) {

            double currentBalance = 500.00;
            System.out.println("your current balance is: $"+ currentBalance);
            System.out.println("Please enter the file name to deposit: ");
            Scanner deposit = new Scanner(System.in);
            String depositAmount = deposit.nextLine();
            File depositFile = new File(depositAmount);
            int nextLine = 1;


            while(deposit.hasNextLine()){
                double numbers = deposit.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("You are about to add: $"+ numbers + " To your Balance");
                currentBalance = currentBalance + numbers;
                System.out.println("Your current balance is: $" + currentBalance);
                nextLine++;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

By the way it will be very helpful if you tell me how to include the first few lines of the code  to use stackoverflow properly

Comment: Which line do you think should read from a file?

Comment: @shmosel thank you for the fast reply. The file is made out of doubles numbers which can be seen as a number in each line. So the code must read throughout all of the lines

Comment: Regarding your [soon to be deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775060/how-to-read-a-txt-file-in-java-and-store-its-values?noredirect=1), You already asked this question here and got a *detailed* answer. Sorry to be blunt, but please put in some effort into learning Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you want to read the file, but you are not doing it anywhere in your program. This line `File depositFile = new File(depositAmount);` doesn't actually read a file, it only creates a `File` class object. I strongly suggest you google **how to read a file in java**. There are plenty of very good tutorials on this subject. Anyways the following code should help you in doing what you are trying to do :-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
// It is a bad practice to start a Java class name with a lower case character
public class IdentifiableImpl {


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Double currentbalance = 500.00;
    System.out.println("To deposit enter 1");
    System.out.println("To Withdrwawl enter 2");
    Scanner depositOrWithdrawl = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choose = depositOrWithdrawl.nextInt();
    if (choose == 1) {

        double currentBalance = 500.00;
        System.out.println("your current balance is: $" + currentBalance);
        System.out.println("Please enter the file name to deposit: ");
        // Scanner deposit = new Scanner(System.in);
        String depositAmount = depositOrWithdrawl.nextLine();
        File depositFile = new File(depositAmount);
        //  Create a stream to read from a file
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(depositFile));
        // String st;
        // int nextLine = 1;
        String input;
        // Read a file line by line
        try {
            while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
                try {
                    // Convert read line into double
                    double numbers = Double.valueOf(input);
                    System.out.println("You are about to add: $" + numbers + " To your Balance");
                    currentBalance = currentBalance + numbers;
                    System.out.println("Your current balance is: $" + currentBalance);
                    // nextLine++;
                } 
// Handle bad input gracefully
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Seems like there is an invalid amount in input file." + input
                            + " Will not proceed further");
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
//Close the stream in finally block
            if(br!=null){
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your loop to scan the file instead of stdin, you need to point the scanner to the file first:

```
deposit = new Scanner(depositFile);
```

Comment: but I already have a scanner with the variable deposit;   Scanner deposit = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: @AmmarA But it's not scanning a file unless you create a new scanner.

Comment: Does that mean I should remove the system.in and add the file name instead? or I should create a new scanner variable?

Comment: @AmmarA You could create a new scanner variable. Or you can just add this line before the loop.

Comment: thank you very much. I've been stuck in this part for two days and thanks to you I fixed it

Comment: shmosel, fyi, a [help vampire](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775060/how-to-read-a-txt-file-in-java-and-store-its-values?noredirect=1)